# calling xref-find-definitions within lisp code

Tags: mark-ring, xref

I want to call *xref-find-definitions* from within my own lisp code and I'm struggling.

> (xref-find-definitions IDENTIFIER)
>
> Find the definition of the identifier at point.

It wants a parameter but I don't understand what parameter to supply because if I call it directly it just reads the name of a function from (point) and finds the source code for me.

As background, I maintain a private mark-ring with functions to (un)rotate-and-go and I want to combine *go-to-source-of-function-named-at-point* and *push-point-onto-private-mark-ring* as one key-combination.

I'm aware of `bury-buffer` and wrote my own `unbury-buffer`.

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The doc for a function (doc string or manual) should describe each of its parameters. It should be clear enough that a user can understand how to call/use the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `xref-find-definitions` programatically by

```
(xref-find-definitions (symbol-name (symbol-at-point)))
```

or if you want to be prompted for an identifier

```
(funcall-interactively #'xref-find-definitions (xref--read-identifier "Find definitions of: "))
```